# convert character to date and calculate age from current date in r

Tags: r

I have a column in dataframe "dob" whic h contains date as a character in format "20-DEC-41" , how can we convert it to date and calculate the age of person till current date.

I have tried `d$dob=as.Date(as.character(d$dob),%d-%B-%Y)` but its throwing an error:

```
"Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "d$dob=as.Date(as.character(d$dob),%d-%"
```

Can anyone please suggest a way to do this

Comment: Try `d$dob=as.Date(as.character(d$dob),%d-%b-%y)`

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that your example refers to the 20th of December 1941? How do you know what century the date is from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d$dob=format(as.Date(d$dob,"%d-%b-%y"),"19%y-%m-%d")

d$dob=as.Date(d$dob)

d$dob=class(d$dob)

d$dob = floor(age_calc(d$dob, units = "years"))